# Como mostrar os itens de uma lista em Python

Tags: python

Pessoal gostaria de pedir uma ajuda a vocês, estou criando um código em Python onde adiciono valores a uma lista e gostaria de mostra-los sem aparecer que esta dentro de uma Lista
O código esta assim:

```py
numero = int(input("Digite um numero que deseje converte para Binario: "))
final = 1
lista = []

while not final < 1: 
  resto = numero % 2
  lista.append(resto)
  divisão = int(numero / 2)
  numero =  divisão
  if numero == 1 or numero == 0 :
    lista.append(numero)
    lista.reverse()
    print(f"O numero convertido para Binario fica {lista}")
    final = 0
```

Output (com o valor de 1029)
O numero convertido para Binario fica [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]

Gostaria que o Output ficasse dessa maneira:
O numero convertido para Binario fica 10000000101

Alguém sabe como poderia fazer isso ou se é possível ?

Link do Codigo https://replit.com/@matheusmarega/Calculadora-de-numeros-Binarios?v=1

Comment: não seria só implementar uma função que implemente esta rotina?

Comment: Pode fazer `''.join(lista)`, isso retornará o valor que precisa

Comment: pois é, eu ia sugerir pra ele implementar uma coisa mais interativa, mas assim funciona @Woss

Comment: @Woss o `join` só funciona caso seja uma string

Comment: @Heinrich Não, funciona para qualquer objeto iterável, não faz nem sentido usá-lo para string, visto que já é uma string haha

Comment: @Woss tenta aí `lista = [1, 2, 3, 4]` `print('\n'.join(lista))` kk. O erro retornado **TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found** (só se teve mudança com base nas versões, utilizo a 3.9.7)

Comment: @Heinrich, vai mandar uma sugestão de como resolver?

Comment: @Heinrich Ah, entendi o que quis dizer, realmente os itens da lista precisam ser strings. Nesse caso pode adaptar o `append` para `append(str(numero))` ou fazer `''.join(str(i) for i in lista)`

Comment: Não seria mais fácil fazer isso https://ideone.com/p7vZm3 ou é um exercício escolar sobre conversão de base?

Answer (score 3):

Tem algumas maneiras que isso pode ser feito, porém depende de qual a sua necessidade.

Podemos fazer um loop interno onde percorremos todos os valores da lista e exibimos ele. Nesse caso a cada print deve haver a configuração do `end` para que não imprima a quebra de linha e após sair do loop ele imprime apenas a quebra de linha

```
for n in lista:
    print(n, end='')
print()
```

Podemos também utilizar o `join` como o @Woss comentou, porém é necessário tratar a lista, pois o `join` funciona com strings e arrays de strings apenas. No 1º caso é feita a conversão na hora de exibir e no 2º caso é feita a conversão na hora de inserir na lista

```
#Caso 1
print(''.join(str(n) for n in lista))

#Caso 2
lista.append(str(numero))
print(''.join(lista))
```

Caso você não vá utilizar esses valores da `lista` para mais nada, ao invés de tratar como uma lista poderia tratar como uma string. No 1º caso os valores são inseridos na ordem que são calculados e por isso é necessário fazer a inversão mais pra frente, já no 2º caso (Obrigado por me lembrar disso @hkotsubo) nós reescrevemos a string para que seja adicionado o número e depois complementado pela informação que já existia na string

```
# Caso 1
lista = ''
lista += '1'
lista += '0'
print(lista[::-1])    #[::-1] faz com que percorra da última posição até a primeira

#Caso 2
lista = ''
lista = '1' + lista
lista = '0' + lista
print(lista)
```

O Python te possibilita muitas maneiras de resolver o problema conforme a sua necessidade

Comment: No último exemplo, poderia fazer `lista = '1' + lista` e `lista = '0' + lista`, pois aí não precisaria inverter a string no final

Comment: @hkotsubo Verdade, não tenho o costume de fazer assim e por isso nem lembrei que existe essa possibilidade. Vou adicionar

Comment: Muito Origado @Heinrich funcionou direitinho!!